# Google Tag Manager: adding Multiple Universal Analytics tracking IDs & auto-event tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have not been able to find clear answers to the following:

- for a client with several country sites (subdomains) I want to use a Google Analytics account per site, plus a roll-up account to collect data of all country sites into one account. I want to use Google Tag Manager to add the analytics to the sites.
  To add 2 Universal Analytics tracking IDs in one container for a site, is it needed to change a name somewhere? As you have to do when adding analytics code manually to a site when using an extra roll-up account.
  If so, what exactly?
- subsequently I want to use autoevent tracking. To track for instance PDF downloads - which are in this case on outbound links. Which is explained in this Justine Cutroni post: http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/07/auto-event-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/
  But instead of using the standard macro for url path, I would rather see the url title or the linktext, as the url path is indecipherable in this case (a bunch of numbers and letters).
  How can that be achieved? Given that the downloads are from dynamic catalogue pages (and thousands of them).

thanks

Comment: Can you split that into two questions ? I think multiple questions per post is discouraged on stackoverflow sites (SO is based on "reputation" which is awarded per anwser accepted by the original poster - that system works better with one question per post).

Answer (score 0):

Why multiple accounts ? This would just work as well with profiles/views. That could potentially save you a bit of headache (if you have multiple trackers you need to push events etc. to all of them - for multiple view you just need a filter in your view settings).

Having said that, you find the settings for the tracker name under "advanced configuration" in  the analytics tag template in the Google Tag Manager (both for ga.js and Universal Analytics). Tick the checkbox with the label "Tracker name" and enter the name (you need to rename at least one the trackers).

Comment: - I am talking about different views for each country site. These are already existing. The roll-up account (view) is new/additional.

Comment: - I am aware the setup in tag manager needs to be replicated for each country site, as each of these sites need a container of their own.
Tag manager however would still give the flexibility of not having to change code in the website(s).

Comment: - But I am still left with the potential confict-issue when adding 2 UA tracking ID's to a site via tag manager. Do I need to change More settings > Advanced configuration > Global function name for the second tracker?